# AWS MediaConvert Python AccessDeniedException: when calling the CreateJob operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, terraform-provider-aws, aws-media-convert

I am trying to create a simple MediaConnect job with Python.
My pipeline is simple. `S3Put` triggers a `Python lambda`, and I am trying to create a simple job.
I created a simple job using AWS Console and the json job is this -

```
{
  "Queue": "arn:aws:mediaconvert:ap-south-1:----:queues/Default",
  "UserMetadata": {},
  "Role": "arn:aws:iam::----:role/mediaConverterRole",
  "Settings": {
    "TimecodeConfig": {
      "Source": "ZEROBASED"
    },
    "OutputGroups": [
      {
        "Name": "File Group",
        "Outputs": [
          {
            "Preset": "System-Generic_Hd_Mp4_Av1_Aac_16x9_640x360p_24Hz_250Kbps_Qvbr_Vq6",
            "Extension": ".mp4",
            "NameModifier": "converted"
          }
        ],
        "OutputGroupSettings": {
          "Type": "FILE_GROUP_SETTINGS",
          "FileGroupSettings": {
            "Destination": "s3://----/"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "Inputs": [
      {
        "AudioSelectors": {
          "Audio Selector 1": {
            "DefaultSelection": "DEFAULT"
          }
        },
        "VideoSelector": {},
        "TimecodeSource": "ZEROBASED",
        "FileInput": "s3://----/videos/sample786.mp4"
      }
    ]
  },
  "AccelerationSettings": {
    "Mode": "DISABLED"
  },
  "StatusUpdateInterval": "SECONDS_60",
  "Priority": 0
}
```

Please note that the `Role` worked fine while using on AWS console. So far this is ok.

Now coming to my pipeline with `s3Put -> Python Lambda -> MediaConnect`, the infrastructure is written using `Terraform`. My `iam.tf` file -

```
# create a role
# reseource_type - resource_name
resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_role" {
  name = "${local.resource_component}-lambda-role"
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
      },
      {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "mediaconvert.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
    }
    ]
  })
}

# create policy 
resource "aws_iam_policy" "policy" {
  name = "${local.resource_component}-lambda-policy"
  policy = jsonencode({
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "logs:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
      }
    ]
  })
}

# attach policy to the role
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "policy_attachment" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.lambda_role.name}"
  policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.policy.arn}"
}
```

The lambda code gets triggered by `S3Put` successfully. But the lambda throws error -

```
(AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateJob operation: User: arn:aws:sts::---:assumed-role/vidstream-inputVideoProcessor-lambda-role/vidstream-inputVideoProcessor is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::---:role/mediaConverterRole
```

I have tried to find `boto3` simple examples but nothing simpler is found online.
The lambda Python Code is here -

```
import json
import logging
import boto3


# initialize logger
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def handler(event, context):

    # get input bucket
    input_bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']

    # get file/object name
    media_object = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']


    # open json mediaconvert template
    with open("job.json", "r") as jsonfile:
        job_object = json.load(jsonfile)

    # prepare data for mediaconvert job
    input_file = f's3://{input_bucket_name}/{media_object}'

    # edit job object
    job_object['Settings']['Inputs'][0]['FileInput'] = input_file

    # updated job object
    logger.info("updated job object")

    # Create MediaConvert client
    mediaconvert_client = boto3.client('mediaconvert')

    try:
        # try to create a job
        mediaconvert_client.create_job(**job_object)

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e)

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(event)
    }
```

The `boto3 MediaConvert` documentation is provided by [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/apireference/python.html)

I am at a loss, no idea what to do. Is there any simpler example anyone can help me with?
**I just need to create a simple job with Lambda that works**, no complexity.

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I solved this issue by putting `iam:PassRole` to lambda policy.

```
{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:PassRole"
        ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
```

So the updated `iam.tf` file is -

```
# create a role
# reseource_type - resource_name
resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_role" {
  name = "${local.resource_component}-lambda-role"
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
      },
      {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "mediaconvert.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
    }
    ]
  })
}

# create policy 
resource "aws_iam_policy" "policy" {
  name = "${local.resource_component}-lambda-policy"
  policy = jsonencode({
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "logs:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
      },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:PassRole"
        ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
})
}


# attach policy to the role
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "policy_attachment" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.lambda_role.name}"
  policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.policy.arn}"
}
```

I first added this to lambda policy from aws console. After that worked I added this on my tf file. Be careful when editing something on console while the main infrastructure is written in `IACs such as Terraform`, this might cause drift if you forget what you have done.